# Cannot log productClick events in GA eCommerce Enhanced and Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, google-tag-manager

I've set up GA eCommerce Enhanced via dataLayer on my website. All GA ecommerce reports work properly except one. GA doesn't log productClick event(

[image]
[image]

data are pushed to dataLayer by execution of next functions

```
    function eProductClick(product) {
    dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'productClick',
        'ecommerce': {
            'click': {
                'actionField': {'list': product.list},
                'products': [{
                    'id': product.id,
                    'name': product.name,
                    'price': product.price,
                    'category': product.category,
                    'position': product.position
                }]
            }
        },
    });
}    

function eAddToBasket(product) {
    dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'addToCart',
        'ecommerce': {
            'currencyCode': 'UAH',
            'add': {
                'products': [{
                    'id': product.id,
                    'name': product.name,
                    'price': product.price,
                    'category': product.category,
                    'quantity': 1
                }]
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Both events are cought by tag manager

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I realy can't find the reason why GA doesn't track Product Views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the event that is not working/missing is the product details action.

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#details

In the report you are looking at the number of product views is not calculated by the number of product click actions but the number of product detail actions. It makes sense as a user could land on a product details page and you would still want that tracked as a product detail view.